# How to configure multiple IIS bindings in Azure

Tags: php, iis, azure, nginx

I'm running IIS8.5 on a Windows 2012R2 server hosted in Azure. I want to run two sites with different domain-names on this IIS-server. One .NET and one running PHP in IIS. Is this possible? How do I do it?

In IIS I've added the domain names under bindings:
domain1.com:8030 (.Net 4.5)
domain2.com:8030 (php wordpress)

In Azure-portal I've added an endpoint HTTP with external port 80 and internal 8030.

I also added my servers external IP to DNS.

Everything was working ok after I added the first site, but after I installed wordpress+php and the second site, both sites now ask for authentication and I get the following errormessage:

401 Authorization Required
nginx/1.7.5

Is this coming from Azure load-balancer?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be azure that changed my servers virtual ip.. I thought the ip-address was static, but aparently not.. my errormessage was from hitting someone else's server..